# Reading WordPress header.php/footer.php to a text string

Tags: wordpress, header, footer, tostring

I am attempting to read the results of the executed header.php/footer.php files as a string of html. Here's the scenario:

There are pages in the site that are developed in a .net environment but they want to share common headers/footers across the entire domain. They wish to have WordPress be the repository for this code and any time there is an update have a PHP cURL call to a .net web service and feed it the new HTML for the header/footers.

I tried calling **get_header()** but that does not return a string (as I anticipated) so then I tried this test solution in functions.php:

```
function write_header() {
$header_content = file_get_contents(get_bloginfo('wpurl').'/index.php' );
$fp = fopen('c:\header.txt', 'a+');
fwrite($fp, $header_content);//just testing the output, this will be a cURL call eventually.
fclose($fp);
}
add_action( 'wp_update_nav_menu', 'write_header' );
```

It seems to be a very heavy handed method of getting the HTML since I'll have to do a lot of string manipulation to parse out the pieces I want. Is there a simpler way of doing this that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple ways you can approach this problem (both are a bit of kludge, but what isnt...). The first would be to create a template in your theme's directory that will include only the header and footer calls -- the body of the template can contain a delimiter string like an html comment, e.g. `<!-- SPLIT HERE -->`.

Request the page through CURL into an output buffer, capturing the resulting response, which you can split into it's component parts using the above delimiter. That will give you your header and footer, complete with the fully rendered tags in the header for css,js, etc. It's not pretty, but it does the job.

The second approach would be an adaptation of the first, which, rather than you doing the splitting, have your .net team take care of it on their end if possible.

### UPDATE

Okay, so there's actually a third option, which I completely forgot about, and that's to use one of WP's features: `wp_remote_get()` http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_API/wp_remote_get

> Retrieves a URL using the HTTP GET method, returning results in an array. Results include HTTP headers and content.

This is what you should get back (excerpted from the API docs):

```
Array
(
    [headers] => Array
        (
            [date] => Thu, 30 Sep 2010 15:16:36 GMT
            [server] => Apache
            [x-powered-by] => PHP/5.3.3
            [x-server] => 10.90.6.243
            [expires] => Thu, 30 Sep 2010 03:16:36 GMT
            [cache-control] => Array
                (
                    [0] => no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
                    [1] => post-check=0, pre-check=0
                )

            [vary] => Accept-Encoding
            [content-length] => 1641
            [connection] => close
            [content-type] => application/php
        )
    [body] => <html>This is a website!</html>
    [response] => Array
        (
            [code] => 200
            [message] => OK
        )

    [cookies] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

All you'd have to do is pass the URL to a page that's using the template I mentioned above, then handle response from `wp_remote_get()`; extract the html content form `[body]` and do your string splitting. Pretty much what you want.

**Further reading**: `wp_remote_retrieve_body()` http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_API/wp_remote_retrieve_body

Comment: Well I tried calling a custom template with just 

`<?php get_header(); ?>
<!-- split here -->
<?php get_footer(); ?>`

I get the following error because the template isn't a complete file:

SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_header() in C:\wamp\www\wp\wp-content\themes\twentyeleven\update.php on line 
etc

Comment: Try regular HTML (no wordpress template calls) and see if you get the same error. The thing is, that template **should** be a complete file given that you're `calling get_header()/get_footer()`, but if you can't even call get_header(), that's problematic. The other thing I would suggest is copy one of your other templates, and strip out the content areas and see what happens.

Comment: The error occurs even if I call the index.php or header.php templates in the current theme.  Seems you can't call the templates directly as they haven't loaded the WP framework so don't have functions such as `get_header()` declared yet.  What I find odd is that you can't just read `get_header()` into a variable.  It doesn't output the content of a file as I would expect it to.

Comment: Can you update your question with the code you're using now so I can see what you've done?

Comment: Ok, I got it to work. I had missed where you said "All you'd have to do is pass the URL to a page that's using the template" I had tried calling the template files directly. It worked once I created a template containing just the header/footer (or each one individually) and THEN based a page off that template and call that page's uri. That executes and returns just the expected portions of the page. If I make 2 seperate templates, one for the header and one for the footer then I don't have to do any splitting either. I am using `file_get_contents(get_bloginfo('wpurl').'/update/' )`

Comment: Totally out of scope (but possibly valuable for other SO readers) consider benchmarking the speed of the results between string splitting vs 2 requests. Alternately, you could send a param to the template in the same request, e.g. fragment=0|1 where 0 = the header, and 1 = the footer to output the desired portions without creating additional clutter in your theme.

Answer (score 2):

If `get_header()` outputs the header for you, try just wrapping it with an `ob_start()` and `ob_get_contents()` to extract the header to a string. You can then discard the output with `ob_end_clean()`. See the [PHP output buffering documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php).

```
ob_start();
get_header();
$header_as_string = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

Comment: Hi Robert, where did you get the empty string? I tried this and got empty string too when I execute the code before `ob_end_clean();` -- but when I move the execution code after `ob_end_clean();` then this solution works like charm!